# PFObject saveInBackgroundWithBlock: with timeout

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, objective-c-blocks

I am using a PFObject to store certain parameters on my Parse backend. One of these parameters is a PFFile containing a video file that can be up to 10MB.

```
PFObject *myPFObject = [PFObject objetWithClassName:@"myObject"];
PFFile *myFile = [PFFile fileWithName:"myFile.mp4" data:mediaData];
[myPFObject setObject:myPFObject forValue:@"media"];   
[myPFObject saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
      //handle response
    }
```

With a decent network connection the method saveInBackgroundWithBlock works great, however if the network connection is slow then it can take a very long time (over 60 seconds) to save this PFObject.

I would like to know the best way to implement a timeout on this operation - i.e if it takes longer than 15 seconds I cancel the operation and tell the user to try saving again with a better network connection. I know I could run an NSTimer to count this timeout duration, but how do I kill the saveInBackgroundWithBlock operation?

Alternatively, are we able to set a specific timeout duration for this parse method anywhere?

Comment: Concerning the way to set a timeout you should look there a "parse guy" explain why this is not possible : https://parse.com/questions/error-handling-when-network-connection-fails . So I think that is not possible to cancel the request once launched because parse will make several attempts automatically even if the upload failed

Comment: i'm come back to you, i'm not sure if it works but you could try setting a NSTimer just before executing the query, and invalidating the timer once the query responds. If the timer is allowed to fire, this means the query hasn't responded within your chosen timeout period and you can update your UI to let the user know. source : https://www.parse.com/questions/handling-retries-in-a-user-friendly-way

Comment: Have you thought about using `saveEventually`? It's meant when you might have a poor connection. So if it's a good connection, it saves. If not, the parse sdk handles save it later when the connection is good

Comment: @Chris Parse Docs : "saveEventually doesn't have a failure mode: its only states are "succeeded" and "not yet succeeded."" Additionally, it's intent is for when the device is offline. The OP's goal is to cancel a working connection if it takes too long.  Parse automatically retries saves, so the NSTimer route would be a good resource. Although, 15 seconds may not be a viable option, you could have a large file that just happens to take longer than 15 seconds to upload, not because of the network, just because it's a large file.

Comment: What happens if I set myPFObject = nil before I get a response? Will this terminate the connection safely?